# Are there n polynomials for which all intersection multiplicities are at least m?

Tags: polynomials, ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, projective-geometry

I don't know whether this is known or not, but I was thinking of the following problem.

Let $n$ and $m$ be natural numbers. Are there $n$ polynomial $f_1,...,f_n\in \mathbb{C}[x]$, such that all of their intersection numbers are at least $m$?

It is also possible to state an even harder question in a more natural (albeit less basic) way: Are there $n$ homogeneous polynomials in 2 variables for which all of their intersection numbers in $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ are at least $m$?

EDIT: Sorry, the comments made me realize I wanted a slightly different condition: that for every $j$ there's a unique $k\neq j$ such that $f_j(0)=f_k(0)$. (In particular, $n$ is assumed to be even.) I will allow the intersection at $x=0$ to not be of multiplicity $\geq m$, but I will ask that over $x\neq 0$ the intersection multiplicity will be $\geq m$.

#### Clarification

The question was posed in a way that algebraic geometers would understand, because I suspect they are most likely to come up with a solution to this question. I wanted to emphasize, however, that intersection multiplicity is something that every high-school student can understand: If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are polynomials with coefficients in $x$, and they meet at say $x=3$, then their intersection multiplicity at $x=3$ is the greatest natural number $l$ such that $(x-3)^l$ divides the polynomial $f_1-f_2$.

Comment: It seems that if you make all your polynomials equal to 0, then you get the desired result (for the 1-variable case).

Comment: In fact, if you make $f_i(x)=x^m$, then all the pair-wise intersections are $2m$.

Comment: Hmmm, let me clarify in the body of the question.


Comment: Given $n$ and $m$, take $n$ distinct polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ and let $a$ be a complex number. Then multiply all your polynomials by $(x-a)^m$.

Comment: Even with the extra condition after the EDIT, take *any* $n$ polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ such that for every $j$ there is a unique $k\neq j$ such that $f_j(0)=f_k(0)$, then you can pick a complex number $a$ such that the property you want will still hold after you multiply all polynomials by $(x-a)^m$.

Comment: @Mahdi: I don't see why that would solve it. It would just change the intersection number over $x=a$, but not over other values of $x$.

Comment: Let's do a quick example: $0,x,1,1+x$ have the desired property at 0. If $m=2$, you're saying to multiply by $(x-1)^2$, say. $1(x-1)^2$ and $x(x-1)^2$ indeed intersect with multiplicity $2$ at $x=1$, but they would also intersect with multiplicity $1$ at some $x\neq 0,1$. So that's undesirable.


Comment: @James: I see my mistake. I deleted my previous comment because it was silly!

Comment: @James: I agree with you, but incidentally the example that you gave is not a good example, because $1(x-1)^2$ and $x(x-1)^2$ only intersect at $x=1$ with multiplicity $3$ actually!

Comment: You're right! So I guess this proves the $m=2$, $n=4$ case. I can't see how this would generalize, though...


Comment: I don't understand what you want. Consider the polynomial $f_i-f_j$. Do you want this to:

a. Only have a single root, with multiplicty $\geq m$?
b. All its roots have multiplicity $\geq m$?
c. Something else?

Comment: @Will: I want that all of its nonzero roots will have multiplicity $\geq m$. Furthermore, I want that for every $i$ there will exist a unique $j$ such that $0$ is a root of $f_i-f_j$.

Comment: @James: Multiplying all $f_i$ with $(x-a)^m$ will not change your condition at $0$, and ensure that all intersection multiplicities at $a$ are at least $2m$. It also doesn't add any other zeros. So why doesn't multiplying with $(x-a)^m$ for all values $a$ that are a zero of some $f_i$ solve your problem?

Comment: Okay, so what I mean is: Start with $n$ polynomials which satisfy your condition at $0$ which are pairwise distinct (and hence each pair intersects in only finitely many places) and then fix their intersection multiplicities as I just described?

Comment: Look at the discussion above -- what you suggest will only make the condition hold at $x=a$, but not for other values of $x$. For example try multiplying $0,x,1,x+1$ (which satisfy the condition over $x=0$) by $(x-3)^2$ and see that there are values where some of these intersect with multiplicity $1$.

Comment: I don't see it. Can you explicitly give me point where the polynomials $0$, $(x-1)^2x$, $(x-1)^2$ and $(x-1)^2(x+1)$ intersect, other than $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @Florian: I think James means pairwise intersections.


Comment: Okay, you said multiply with $(x-3)^2$, but these polynomials intersect at $1$, so that's what you'd want to fix. Multiplication with $(x-3)^2$ is adding $3$ as an intersection point, but other than that, the intersection multiplicity at $1$ (and everywhere else) remains unchanged (as one would expect).

Comment: @Mahdi: I realize that. I just overlooked the intersection between $0$ and $x+1$ at $-1$. But then I still don't see why multiplying all four polynomials with $(x-1)^2(x+1)^2$ doesn't fix things.

Comment: @ Florian: If I am not overlooking anything, I think it does fix it! So in general, you say multiply all polynomials by $(x-a_i)^m$, where $a_i$'s are *all* the points where a pair of polynomials intersect.

Comment: @Florian: $0$ and $(x-1)^2(x+1)$ intersect with multiplicity $1$ at $x=-1$.

Comment: @Mahdi: Yes, that's indeed what I mean.

Comment: @James: Yeah, I overlooked that one, but my later comment fixed this.

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Comment: @Florian: Why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: @Mahdi: I just did. I didn't at first because I wasn't quite sure I didn't somehow misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so here's the long version of what I already said in the comments:

Start by picking $g_1,\ldots,g_n\in \mathbb C[x]$ such that $g_i\neq g_j$ whenever $i\neq j$ which satisfy the prescribed condition at $0$ (that's not hard). Since $g_i-g_j\neq 0$ for each $i\neq j$, there will be only finitely many $0\neq a\in\mathbb C$ such that $g_i(a)-g_j(a)=0$ for some pair $i,j$ with $i\neq j$. Call these values  $a_1,\ldots,a_k$. Then define 
$$
   f_i(x) := \left(\prod_{j=1}^k (x-a_j)^m\right)\cdot g_i(x)
$$ 
Those $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ have pairwise intersection also in $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ (and possibly in $0$), but now with multiplicty at least $2m$ (except in $0$, where the intersection multiplicty is left as it was). The condition at zero is clearly preserved and we didn't add any further intersection points either.

Comment: Just a small remark: we should only include the nonzero $a_i$'s, otherwise we will ruin the prescribed condition at zero. 